# What does '$(this)' contains in a below javascript function code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this, alert

Following is the code of a function :

```
$Core.notification =
{   
    bDebug: false,

    update: function()
    {
        setTimeout('$.ajaxCall("notification.update", "", "GET");', 1000);
    },

    setTitle: function()
    {
        var iTotal = 0;
        var sTitle = $('title').html();

        $('.holder_notify_count').each(function(){ alert($(this));
            iTotal += parseInt($(this).html());
        });

        var newTitle = '';      
        var aMatches = sTitle.match(/(\([0-9]*\))/i);
        if (aMatches !== null && isset(aMatches[1])){
            if (iTotal > 0){
                newTitle = '(' + iTotal + ') ' + sTitle.replace(aMatches[1], '');
                //$('title').html(newTitle.replace('#',''));
                // document.title = newTitle.replace('#', '');
            }
            else{
                //$('title').html(aMatches[1].replace('#',''));
                // document.title = aMatches[1].replace('#', '');
            }
        }
        else{
            if (iTotal > 0){
                //$('title').prepend('(' + iTotal + ') '); // it doesnt work in IE8
                // ie8 doesnt like hashes           
                var NewTitle = document.title.replace('#','');              
                // document.title = '(' + iTotal + ') ' + NewTitle;

            }
            else{
            }
        }

        if (getParam('notification.notify_ajax_refresh') > 0)
        {
            setTimeout('$.ajaxCall("notification.update", "", "GET");', (this.bDebug ? 10000 : (getParam('notification.notify_ajax_refresh') * 60000)));
        }
    }
};
```

Consider only the following two lines from above code, ignore rest of the code :

```
$('.holder_notify_count').each(function(){
                iTotal += parseInt($(this).html());
            });
```

I'm not able to understand what does `$(this)` contain? I tried `alert($(this));` inside `$('.holder_notify_count').each(function(){.....});`

But it only printed `[object Object]` so I'm not able to find out what `$(this)` contain and how should I print it?

Thanks.

Comment: @Satpal: But it refers to which element? That's my question to you.

Comment: it refers to the "current" element of the iteration. Each element will be `this` once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(this) is the object ($('.holder_notify_count'))
$(this).html() means the html inside $('.holder_notify_count')

Answer (score 1):

From [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> The `.each()` method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

As per your code

```
$('.holder_notify_count').each(function(){

});
```

`this` in the callback method refers to underlying DOM element `.holder_notify_count`

Comment: But it refers to which element? That's my question to you.

Comment: @user2839497 It refers to `'.holder_notify_count'`

Comment: element $('.holder_notify_count')

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.holder_notify_count').each(
```

will iterate over each element having class `.holder_notify_count`

The `$(this)` in the each callback is a jQuery object containing the particular `DOM` element `.holder_notify_count` of that iteration.

It is contained in a jQuery wrapper and has access to all jQuery API calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is every jQuery object from the element's set that you iterate over in this `.each` loop. So it is every element that has class named `holder_notify_count`, as indicated in jQuery selector `.holder_notify_count`.

It is the same as you would assign it `$('.holder_notify_count')[0]`, then `$('.holder_notify_count')[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Under  `.each()` alert does not work. try `console.log($(this).html());`.

Answer (score 0):

Satpal did give you the correct answer , but heres the functional breakdown to make you understand better :

```
         <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Hello-1</li>
            <li>Hello-2</li>
        </ul>
```

Jquery ::

```
$(function () {
            $('ul li').each(function(){
                console.log($(this).text());
            })
        });
```

The above code will print the following :

```
"Hello" 
"Hello-1" 
"Hello-2"
```

Why ?

1st notice how we are selecting `$('ul li')` , we are selecting all the li's inside the ul , nowh each will iterate over all the li's **SO** , on the 1st iteartion $(this) is the 1st `li` on the secound $(this) is the secound `li` abd on the 3rd $(this) is the 3rd `li`